# Printing Score - Pygame

Tags: python, text, printing, pygame

Does anyone know how I can get the score to be displayed on the screen of my game?

So far I have this code:

```
for bullet in bullet_list:

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

        for block in block_hit_list:
        explosion.play()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        score += 10
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
        text = font.render(score, 1, (WHITE))
        textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2)
        background.blit(text, textpos)

    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
```

However, I recieve this error once I launch the game and shoot a bullet:

"text = font.render(score, 1, (WHITE))

TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes"

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so first of all you asked how to correctly draw the site which would be just like how the previous answer did it, but then you are a but wrong in the way you blit  it to the screen.

You currently have the score blit to the screen every time through the for loop, this causes it to have the effect you're experiencing. This should be just after the for loop.
Example:

```
for bullet in bullet_list: 
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True) 
    for block in block_hit_list:
        explosion.play()
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet) 
        score += 10
        #removed this line!!!! ~ font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36) 
        #removed this line to!!!! ~ text = font.render(score, 1, (WHITE)) 
        #remove this line also!!! ~ textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2) 
        #finally remove this line!!!! ~ background.blit(text, textpos) 
    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
        bullet_list.remove(bullet) 
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
#add in those removed lines after your for loop.
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 36)
text = font.render(score, 1, (WHITE))
textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=background.get_width()/2)
background.blit(text, textpos)
```

This should work. Please tell me if you need any further help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this works perfectly but I still have an issue with scores being displayed on top of each other continuously? Rather than displaying 10 then clearing the score before 20 is displayed, it displays 10 on top of 20 etc leaving me with unreadable text

Comment: @Oscar Could you post your current code preferably a bit more of the mainloop?

Comment: @Oscar OK you should be blitting the text to the screen not the background. What is happening is that you draw the score to the background, but the backgrounds never gets cleared. You want to clear whatever you're drawing the text to. So to fix this, draw the text to the screen and not to the background, also draw the text after you draw the background to the screen.

Comment: Ah, this works great! Thanks so much for your help, I have another question to do with firing the bullet, I want the ship to only shoot when the space bar is pushed however it currently shoots when any key is pressed, also the "bullet" seems to be off center, any idea how to fix these issues? Thanks a lot for your replies :)

Comment: @Oscar sorry for delayed response, but in the line `elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:` you just need to check which key is pressed by using this: `elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:` More information regarding this is found at http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the score into a string.

```
text = font.render(str(score), 1, (WHITE))
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Only one slight issue, scores appear on top of themselves if more than 1 point is scored, is there any way I can fix this? :) Thanks so much for your reply